# implementation of genetic algorithm for spell checker

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I want to implement the spell checker which will checks the spelling in a text file and outputs the errors and corrections. I want to create this using python.

But, the main thing is I want to implement that with using genetic algorithm. How can I implement the genetic algorithm for spell checker?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Paste some code you wrote and describe why it doesn't behave as you want.

Comment: emm, not really sure of what the question is here, do you want help on how to implement a genetic algorithm in general? or do you want help with implementing one in python? or do you want help on a genetic algorithm for spell-checking? (not really sure how spellchecking works, and how you would use a GA for it though? is the GA to find the best matching correctly written word?)

Comment: @usethedeathstar : Hi, I have read about genetic algorithm but I am not sure how I have to implement that for spell checker. Algorithm will find out the spell errors and mistakes and prints the same.

Comment: @dnet : I have read about genetic algorithm but have no idea how to implement that with spell checker. I want help for the same.

Comment: so your spellchecker works, but you are now at the point of suggesting correctly typed words, for which you want to use a genetic algorithm? I dont see the link to a GA, like how would your cost-function be?

Comment: algorithm selects best among best. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm . but, i dont understand if i do not have any database then only using words from text files, how can I generate best among best and search for mistakes?

Comment: yeah, i know how a GA works ;-) but i just dont see the point of using it here? if you got a list of words which are correctly spelled, and you find a word which aint in there, you just get whatever word is in the list of correctly spelled words, but which is least different from the wrong-spelled one. No need for a GA there? The problem you will get is when you got two words that are only one character off, how to select the best one there. How you would determine which one is best, that is something else. Can you describe a bit more what your current approach is?

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect my idea here to be perfect or optimal, but it might be a good starting point for you if you decide to go this route.  A genetic algorithm may not be the best choice for a spell checker though.

For a genetic algorithm, you need to have a starting population, a way to pass the genes to the "next generation" (crossover), a definite means of creating mutations, and a way of selecting which ones are passed on to the next generation (aka a fitness function).  Along with this you'll need, of course, a corpus.  You can try the dictionary.com API if it's any good (I've never used it) http://www.programmableweb.com/api/dictionary.com.

For the starting population, you have the horrible issue in that your starting population will be thousands of the exact same word (i.e. ['hello']*1000).  From here you can just check if it's a word, then if it is just return True (because grammar checking there vs their vs they're will be a pain in the ass).

To start off, you'll need to rely entirely on mutations to gain diversity, so maybe make mutations more likely if it's an earlier generation, and once the diversity grows the chance of mutation decreases.  Mutations can be any of: insert a random letter somewhere, remove a letter somewhere, change a letter somewhere, do more than one of these.

For your fitness function, your best bet will be to use a sequence alignment algorithm.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment.  If you REALLY want to get advanced, try creating phonetic spellings for each word in your population and see if they match anything in the corpus, and increase score based on that (i.e. tho and though would have the same pronunciation).  I cannot claim to know anything about that.  Bare in mind all of this will slow down your application horribly, so keep that in mind.  It might be best to limit your population to 1000-2000.

For your crossover, you should take a few of your samples (early on you may need to use roulette to pick which will be the most fit, but later on you can use tournament for speed purposes).  Again you can use the sequence alignment between each "parent", and then decide which letter to pull from each parent (i.e. soeed vs s_eeo can come out to be soeed, seed, seeo, or soeeo).

Don't take this as an expert solution, plus I only put a few minutes of thought into this, but it could be a good start if you decide to use a genetic algorithm.